# XPath between two elements

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a Word 2003 XML document that I am trying to search for certain elements in.  I have been able to do simple XPath queries to find single elements, but I am having difficulty coming up with a query to search between two elements:

```
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:instrText> DOCPROPERTY  EvidenceBase  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>EvidenceBase</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
    </w:r>
```

I am searching for the above XML, that has a w:r with a w:fldChar in it which has an attribute of w:fldCharType with value of "begin". It should return every element until it hits a w:r with a w:fldChar in it which has an attribute of w:fldCharType with value of "end".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//w:r[preceding-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin'] and following-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end']]
```

Mind that the prefix `w` would need to be bound to the proper namespace for the XPath expression namespace context. How this is done depends on how you use the XPath (XSLT, Java, C#...).

Also, this would be more complex if there's multiple, possibly nested "begin" and "end" markers.

Answer (score 1):

**In any similar problem one can use the Kayessian formula for nodeset intersection**.

If we have two node-sets `$ns1` and `$ns2`, then all nodes that belong to both nodesets are selected by this XPath expression:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

**In your case you have to just substitute `$ns1` with**:

```
//w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin'][1]/following-sibling::*
```

..

**and substitute `$ns2` with**:

```
//w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end'][1]/preceding-sibling::*
```

The resulting XPath expression may seem too-complicated, but what you gain is the ability to solve any such problem very easily and almost mechanically:

```
  /*/w:r
      [w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin']/following-sibling::*
     [count(. | /*/w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end']
                                     /preceding-sibling::*
            )
     =
      count(/*/w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end']
                                     /preceding-sibling::*)
     ]
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:w="some:namespace">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/w:r
          [w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin']/following-sibling::*
         [count(. | /*/w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end']
                                         /preceding-sibling::*
                )
         =
          count(/*/w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end']
                                         /preceding-sibling::*)
         ]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<t xmlns:w="some:namespace">
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="before-begin"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:instrText> DOCPROPERTY  EvidenceBase  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>EvidenceBase</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="after-end"/>
    </w:r>
</t>
```

**exactly the wanted elements are selected and copied to the output**:

```
<w:r xmlns:w="some:namespace">
   <w:instrText> DOCPROPERTY  EvidenceBase  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r xmlns:w="some:namespace">
   <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r xmlns:w="some:namespace">
   <w:t>EvidenceBase</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Comment: +1 - I appreciate the elegance of the Kayessian formula, but I was surprised at first to see (after a few *very* informal benchmarks) that this performed much slower than the "naive" solution in @G_H's answer. (Tests using Saxon.)

Comment: @lwburk: Thanks. Yes, this is a "quick and dirty" solution and it maynot be efficient for large node-sets. Anyway, in XPath 2.0 the `intersect` operator could probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of preceding begins is different from the number of ends, we must be between a begin and end. Therefore:

```
w:r[count(preceding-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin']) != count(preceding-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are all about XPath 1.0. I will add solutions in XPath 2.0 and XPath 3.x.

**For XPath 2.0**

We can use the `intersect` keyword to simplify the XPath.

```
w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin']/following-sibling::*
intersect
w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end']/preceding-sibling::*
```

**For XPath 3.x**

We can declare two variables to get the index of the start and end elements. And filter the lists by the two variables.

```
let $x=:index-of(w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin']),
$y=:index-of(w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end']),
w:r[position()>=$x and position()<=$y]
```

The solution in XPath 3.x will be much faster because the time complexity is only n, while for XPath 2.0 and 1.0, the time complexity is n-squared.