# xslt select between 2 values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is it possible to select only those values that lay between 2 given values using xslt?

i.e.

```
<value>1</value> 
<value>1.2</value>
<value>1.3</value>
<value>1.4</value>
<value>1.5</value>
<value>2</value> 
<value>2.1</value>
<value>2.3</value>
<value>2.4</value>
<value>2.5</value>
```

I only want to display values between 1 and 2.

Comment: Which XSLT version do you use? With 2.0 there are operators `<<` and `>>` so you could use `//value[. >> //value[. = 1] and . << //value[. = 2]]`. Note that inside of XSLT you need of course escape `<<` as `&lt;&lt;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath between two elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181856/xpath-between-two-elements) or [XPath Get Elements that are between 2 elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489326/xpath-get-elements-that-are-between-2-elements) or [Selecting siblings between two nodes using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428104/selecting-siblings-between-two-nodes-using-xpath)

Comment: Do you mean "between" as in "numerically greater than the minimum and less than the maximum" or as in "after an element with one value and before another element with a different value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the other answer I prefer to go with Identity Override

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="value[. &lt; 1 or . &gt; 2]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs:

```
<root>
  <value>1</value> 
  <value>1.2</value>
  <value>1.3</value>
  <value>1.4</value>
  <value>1.5</value>
  <value>2</value> 
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly:

```
select="value[. &gt; 1 and . &lt; 2]"
```

if you want to include 1 and 2:

```
select="value[. &gt;= 1 and . &lt;= 2]"
```

if the top and bottom limits are in variables (using $min and $max as examples here):

```
select="value[. &gt; $min and . &lt; $max]"
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the values are sorted (as in the provided XML document), this would be faster -- especially in the cases when there are many `valu` elements following the last wanted `value` element**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vStart" select=
   "(*[.>=1][1]
   |
    *[1]
    )
     [last()]
   "/>

  <xsl:variable name="vEnd" select=
   "($vStart/following-sibling::*[. > 2][1]
                             /preceding-sibling::*[1]
   |
    *[last()]
    )
     [1]
   "/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPosRange" select=
  "count($vEnd/preceding-sibling::*) - count($vStart/preceding-sibling::*)"/>

  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "$vStart|$vStart/following-sibling::*[not(position() > $vPosRange)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<t>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>1.2</value>
    <value>1.3</value>
    <value>1.4</value>
    <value>1.5</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>2.1</value>
    <value>2.3</value>
    <value>2.4</value>
    <value>2.5</value>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<value>1</value>
<value>1.2</value>
<value>1.3</value>
<value>1.4</value>
<value>1.5</value>
<value>2</value>
```

**Do note**:

**In practice this gives us a pure XPath 1.0 solution**, as we can substitute `$vPosRange`, `$vStart` and `$vEnd` with the XPath expressions that they are defined with.