# Xpath to select between tags

Tags: xpath

This question may be asked here, I searched for hours but not able to figure out how to select between the nodes.

I am a novice in XPath selection, I am trying to select all the li under specific h6, the challenge here is the all the h6 have the same class attributes so not able to identify the unique identifier, when I type `//h6/ui/li/span` it gets all li in the document under all the h6.

```
<h6> Text1 </h6>
<ul>
    <li><span> list1 </span></li>
    <li><span> list2 </span></li>
    <li><span> list3 </span></li>
</ul>
<div> </div>
<h6> Text 2</h6>
```

Not sure how to proceed, first time I am writing a question here, let me know if more information is required.

Any help appreciated

Comment: With XPath questions, please say which version of XPath you are using, since 1.0, 2.0, and 3.1 are all in active use, and many problems that are hard with XPath 1.0 become easy with later versions. There are tags you can use to identify the version.

Comment: Noted! will do it in the future. I am using XPath in scrapy, so it's XPATH 1.0

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you do not tell us the version of your XPath. There are XPath 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0/3.1. There are different. Each is built on the previous version.

## For XPath 1.0

You can refer to [XPath between two elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181856/xpath-between-two-elements).

The idea is to get two lists, one is from `<h6> Text1 </h6>` to end (following-sibling), the other from `<h6> Text 2</h6>` to start(preceding-sibling). Then, get the intersect of the two lists.

In the last predicate, we put the node to the list, get the count, and we compare the count of the list. If they equal, the node is in the list.

The following is the code in Python for your problem:

```py
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML("""
<root>
<h6> Text 1 </h6>
<ul>
    <li><span> list1 </span></li>
    <li><span> list2 </span></li>
    <li><span> list3 </span></li>
</ul>
<div> </div>
<h6> Text 2 </h6>
</root>
""")

root.xpath("h6[text()=' Text 2 ']/preceding-sibling::*[count(.|/root/h6[text()=' Text 1 ']/following-sibling::*)=count(/root/h6[text()=' Text 1 ']/following-sibling::*)]")
```

## For XPath 2.0

There is an `intersect` keyword, so the previous XPath can be simplified to:

```
h6[text()=' Text 1 ']/following-sibling::* intersect h6[text()=' Text 2 ']/preceding-sibling::*
```

## For XPath 3.0/3.1

You can use `variable declaration` to find the start position and end position first. And select elements between the two positions.

```
let $x := index-of(h6[text()=' Text 1 ']),
    $y := index-of(h6[text()=' Text 2 '])
return *[position()>=$x and position()<=$y]
```

The solution in XPath 3.x will be much faster because the time complexity is only *n*, while for XPath 2.0 and 1.0, the time complexity is *n-squared*.

Again, I do not know your XPath version. for `lxml`, you can only use XPath 1.0. For other packages, please find out yourself.

Comment: You could replace the 3.1 solution with `let $x := h6[.=' Text 1 ']), $y := h6[.=' Text 2 ']) return *[.>>$x and .<<$y]`. You could also retrofit this to 2.0 by using "for .. in" instead of "let .. :=".

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to get required output

```
//ul[preceding-sibling::h6[1][normalize-space()="Text1"]]/li
```

Comment: Thanks @jason, this worked, I had to include "span" tag for it to work. `code` //ul[preceding-sibling::h6[1][normalize-space()='Text1']]/li/span/text().
But the challenge here is to specify the h6 position 'h6[1]'

Answer (score 0):

Following XPATH worked for my requirement
xpath("//h6[text()='Text 1']/following::ul[1]/li/span/text()")

I selected the H6 and following first UL